# Two Images or DIV with same coordinates (position) on a webpage?

Tags: html, image

I was wondering what will happen if
I set two images,div elements with
same position ( same coordinates)
on a webpage?

Will first Image get that position?
Will second Image get that position?
Will they get superimposed?

What will happen if the two DIV
elements containing data have same
coordinates on a webpage?

Also as upto I know location of
Images can be set via CSS but is
there any other method exist to set
the location of Image or DIV?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The second div or image will be placed on top of the first. You can use this to your advantage. For example, you can place the second div on top, with opacity:0.5 and you'll see through it. This is often used when showing a modal dialog.

This simple example shows you.

By the way, there are lots of tools such as jsFiddle or CodePen that can be used to try things like this on your own.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#d1 {
  background: blue;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

#d2 {
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1">
  Div #1
</div>
<div id="d2">
  Div #2
</div>
```

Comment: " The second div or image will be placed on top of the first. "  You meant the second Div or Image will get the location which was same for both ?  And will this behavior remain same for every web browsers ?   Thanks for your answer.?

Comment: It is the same for every modern web browser that supports CSS. In my example, the second div sits right on top of the first, since they have the exact same positioning. If you want a few divs, images, etc and you want to *force* one to be on top, you can use the `z-index` CSS property as well.